# How to show/hide a dash-cytoscape object on a dashboard?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I am currently working on a Plotly Dash webapp where I want to show/hide a cytoscape graph using either display style on a parent div or by redrawing it (I am also opened to other solutions), none of what I tried worked.
Is there something I am missing?

Here is a code example showing this issue:

```python
import json

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html
import requests
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


def load_json(st):
    if 'http' in st:
        return requests.get(st).json()
    else:
        with open(st, 'rb') as f:
            x = json.load(f)
        return x


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server


# Load Data
elements = load_json('https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/data.json')
stylesheet = load_json('https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/cy-style.json')

# App
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dbc.Button("display", id="btn_display"),
        dbc.Button("redraw", id="btn_redraw"),
        html.Div(
            [
                cyto.Cytoscape(
                    id='cytoscape-responsive-layout',
                    elements=elements,
                    stylesheet=stylesheet,
                    layout={
                        'name': 'cose',
                    },
                    responsive=True
                )
            ],
            id="div",
            style={"display": "inherit"}
        )
    ]
)

# callbacks
@app.callback(Output("div", "style"),
              Input("btn_display", "n_clicks"))
def style_toggle(n: int):
    disp = {"display": "none" if (n is not None and n % 2 == 1) else "inherit"}
    return disp


@app.callback(Output("div", "children"),
              Input("btn_redraw", "n_clicks"))
def redraw(_):
    return [
        cyto.Cytoscape(
            id='cytoscape-responsive-layout',
            elements=elements,
            stylesheet=stylesheet,
            layout={
                'name': 'cose',
            },
            responsive=True
        )
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8052)
```

The `style_toggle` callback correctly hide the div but when it set back the display style to `inherit` the graph does not reappear.

The `redraw` callback seems to have no effect.

And here is my env:

```
$ python -m pip list | grep dash
dash                      1.20.0              
dash-bootstrap-components 0.11.1              
dash-core-components      1.16.0              
dash-cytoscape            0.2.0               
dash-daq                  0.5.0               
dash-extensions           0.0.51              
dash-html-components      1.1.3               
dash-renderer             1.9.1               
dash-table                4.11.3              
jupyter-dash              0.4.0
```

EDIT: It turns out the `responsive=True` parameter was the cause, I have reorganized my dashboard to work without... If someone has a workaround which keeps the responsiveness that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

RadaKk, here is a possible workaround returning the cytoscape elements as empty or filled to display it or not:

```
import json

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html
import requests
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate


def load_json(st):
    if 'http' in st:
        return requests.get(st).json()
    else:
        with open(st, 'rb') as f:
            x = json.load(f)
        return x


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server


# Load Data
default_elements = load_json('https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/data.json')
stylesheet = load_json('https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/cy-style.json')

# App
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dbc.Button("display", id="btn_display"),
        dbc.Button("redraw", id="btn_redraw"),
        html.Div(
            [
                cyto.Cytoscape(
                    id='cytoscape-responsive-layout',
                    elements=default_elements,
                    stylesheet=stylesheet,
                    layout={
                        'name': 'cose',
                    },
                    responsive=True
                )
            ],
            id="div",
            style={"display": "block"}
        )
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("cytoscape-responsive-layout", "elements"),
              Input("btn_display", "n_clicks"),
              prevent_initial_call=True)
def redraw(n:int):
    if (n is not None and n % 2 == 1):
        elements=[]
    else:
        elements=default_elements
    return elements


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8052)
```